# DataSource binding Dataview to ListBox C#

Tags: c#, listbox, datasource, dataview

I would like to add a Dataview as a DataSource to my ListBox Component. 
The DataView gets data from a DataTable which is filled/updated from another Thread with data from a COM port. So the ListBox should be updated if necessary. My DataView delivers correct data and the binding throws no errors but no Items are present.

Here is my code:

UI code:

```
 lBoxIdentifier.DataSource = dataClass.identifierView;
 lBoxIdentifier.DisplayMember = "id";
 lBoxIdentifier.ValueMember = "id";
```

DataClass contains:

```
 identifierTable = new DataTable();
 identifierTable.TableName = "identifier";
 var identifier = new DataColumn("id", Type.GetType("System.String"));
 identifierTable.Columns.Add(identifier);

 identifierView = new DataView(identifierTable);
 dataView.AllowDelete = false;
 dataView.AllowEdit = false;
 dataView.AllowNew = false;
```

Comment: i thought it acts like a datagridview where the framework do the synchronization

Comment: but my grid view do get all data from the table datatable > dataview > gridview i work on my datatable and change or add some rows, my dataview contains a filter row statement and is binded to dgv

Comment: sure? because i dont and it still works. why should there be a binding if i have to refresh it every time, so i could just add the rows on the form itself`?

Comment: You are right. I guess a DGV does indeed refresh the data (at least as soon as it has time to do so.) But so does a ListBox.. You may want to code the [dataview.listchanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.listchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to see if it gets called.. Atm I suspect your threading to be the cause, but I've been wrong before. (Btw a main reason for databinding is separation of data and view(s))

Comment: I did that already and it works but i wondered if theres no "easy" way to accomplish the databinding like the dgv

Comment: Well, just as I wrote: The ListBox behaves __just like__ a DGV! The only difference is that here you need to set (at least) the  `DisplayMember`. If yours doesn't, there is something else that is different in your code.